# Dagger : Cannot have two modules unless I mark one as incomplete and have other include the first one?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have two really simple modules like

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class
        }
)
public class PersonModule
{
    @Provides
    public Person providePerson()
    {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

And another module like

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class
        }
)
public class CarModule
{
    @Provides
    public Car provideCar()
    {
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

In my Android activity I Inject both `Person` and `Car`

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Inject
    Person person;

    @Inject
    Car car;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        // Use person and car...
    }
}
```

This fails at compile time with

```
Error:(14, 8) Gradle: error: No injectable members on com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.Person. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.MainActivity for com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.CarModule

Error:(14, 8) Gradle: error: No injectable members on com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.Car. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.MainActivity for com.t3methods.daggerapp.app.PersonModule
```

It works if I change one of the modules to to incomplete (by setting `complete = false`) and adding an includes in the other module which points to this incomplete module

```
@Module(
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class
        },
        includes = {
                PersonModule.class
        }
)
public class CarModule
....

@Module(
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class
        },
        complete = false
)
public class PersonModule
....
```

Can someone explain or point me in the right direction as to what exactly is happening here? With Dagger, I feel like I am just shooting in the dark, adding and deleting annotation parameters randomly till things work without understanding.

Comment: Jake Warton Dagger Sample App https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020

Comment: I didn't see any use of Dagger, it makes code complex and debugging hell. Am I right? what is use of this in real world app?

Comment: Well, it does have a learning curve, but once you do learn, it tends to simplify your code.

Comment: One thing that make it very absurd is you have to tell Module itself where you are going to use it... why? I have seen Jake Warton Presentation https://parleys.com/play/529bde2ce4b0e619540cc3ae/chapter0/about but I still feel its not mature enough to use it in production app.

Comment: Come Dagger 2.0 and that won't be needed anymore. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dagger-discuss/0O904ARp1kc/ThxmFoIOX5sJ

Comment: It is restricting you rather than giving you ease in development. It makes more difficult to image your object graph. it can cause memory over flow exception if not handled in correct way. It will be a debugging hell to debug object graph as there will be nothing for you to see. all you have to use your imagination :) I would prefer not to use it... as many other people. We need to keep Android development simple not to make it a more like a hell :)

Comment: Let's say login functionality. What you need is LoginActivity, LoginInteractor, LoginInteractorImpl, InteractorModule, LoginPresenter... see so much code. although less dependable but there is always a trade off.. it depends what you chose. :)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fwg-NsMKYtYxeEWe82rISIHjNrtdqonfiHgp8-PQ7m8/edit# see this Dagger 2.0 new annotations..and more stuff.. still have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out an easy way to circumvent this whole complete and includes cycle.

I create a master module which includes all other modules and then only add this one module to the `ObjectGraph`

```
@Module(
        includes = {
                CarModule.class,
                PersonModule.class,
                AnimalModule.class
        },
        library = true
)
public class AppModule
....
```

The included modules all have `complete = false`. Is this the right way to do this? :-|